# How to set distances between widgets in the same row in sidebar of shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny dashboard below and I want to set specific distancing between the actionbuttons. The more I increase the width of the sidebar the more space I get between them but I want to set it with a more standard way.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(title = "My dashboard"),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width=1000,
        fluidRow(

            column(2,
                   div(style="display:inline-block",actionButton('ExampleIRD', 'Interest Rates Derivatives'),width=6)
            )       
            ,

            column(2,
                   div(style="display:inline-block",actionButton('ExampleCredit', 'Credit Derivatives'),width=6)
            ),

            column(2,
                   div(style="display:inline-block",actionButton('ExampleComm', 'Commodity Forwards'),width=6)
            ),

            column(2,
                   div(style="display:inline-block",actionButton('ExampleIRDCredit', 'IR + Credit Derivatives'),width=6)
            ),

            column(2,
                   div(style="display:inline-block",actionButton('ExampleIRDCommMargined', 'IR + Commodity Derivatives Margined'),width=6)
            )

        )
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(

    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {




}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `padding` in UI, as shown in the code below:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(title = "My dashboard"),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width=1000,
                             fluidRow(

                               column(2,
                                      div(style="display:inline-block; padding: 5px 5px 5px 1px;",actionButton('ExampleIRD', 'Interest Rates Derivatives'))
                               ),

                               column(2,
                                      div(style="display:inline-block; padding: 5px 1px 5px 25px;",actionButton('ExampleCredit', 'Credit Derivatives'))
                               ),

                               column(2,
                                      div(style="display:inline-block; padding: 5px 3px 5px 1px;",actionButton('ExampleComm', 'Commodity Forwards'))
                               ),

                               column(2,
                                      div(style="display:inline-block; padding: 5px 3px 5px 1px;",actionButton('ExampleIRDCredit', 'IR + Credit Derivatives'))
                               ),

                               column(3,
                                      div(style="display:inline-block; padding: 5px 3px 5px 1px;",actionButton('ExampleIRDCommMargined', 'IR + Commodity Derivatives Margined'))
                               )

                             )
  ),
```

and you will get the following output:  [image: output]